# Celery backend parameter

Tags: celery

Im newbie to Celery and trying to understand backend parameter in Celery.

I tried this document - http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html and was able to execute a tasks.

I see this result in the worked window -

```
[2015-07-04 15:45:32,633: INFO/MainProcess] Task tasks.add[95eee2f4-8491-4200-8628-30ea131d9777] succeeded in 0.0166970053688s: 20
```

But, I'm not sure where the results are being stored when I use my backend parameter.

Here is my backend parameter-

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',backend='amqp')
```

Answer (score 0):

Results of tasks are stored in dedicated message-queues in the AMQP implementation you are using (most probably, RabbitMQ)!

Since you have read the document you provide the link to, I am assuming you know how to retrieve results & are only interested in knowing *where* the result is stored.